# How to fix "A comma or a closing bracket was expected"?

Tags: mysql, sql

I get "A comma or a closing bracket was expected" error when trying to execute this SQL code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `player_vehicles` (
  `#` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `steam` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `citizenid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vehicle` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mods` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `plate` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `fakeplate` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `garage` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fuel` int(11) DEFAULT 100,
  `engine` float DEFAULT 1000,
  `body` float DEFAULT 1000,
  `state` int(11) DEFAULT 1,
  `depotprice` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `drivingdistance` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `health` longtext NOT NULL '[{"value":100,"part":"electronics"},{"value":100,"part":"fuelinjector"},{"value":100,"part":"brakes"},
{"value":100,"part":"radiator"},{"value":100,"part":"driveshaft"},{"value":100,"part":"transmission"},{"value":100,"part":"clutch"}]'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Error message:

```sql
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'[{"value":100,"part":"electronics"},{"value":100,"part":"fuelinjector"},{"value":100,"part":"brakes"},{"value":100,"part":"radiator"},{"value":100,"part":"driveshaft"},{"value":100,"part":"transmission"},{"value":100,"part":"clutch"}]'" at position 816)
```

Can someone please help, I can't figure this out?

Comment: This should not be there: '[{"value":100,"part":"electronics"},{"value":100,"part":"fuelinjector"},{"value":100,"part":"brakes"},
{"value":100,"part":"radiator"},{"value":100,"part":"driveshaft"},{"value":100,"part":"transmission"},{"value":100,"part":"clutch"}]'. If you intended it to be the default value for that field, add `DEFAULT` in front of it (before the opening apostrophe), e.g. `DEFAULT '[{"value":100`...

Comment: DEFAULT will not work for a column defined as longtext.

Comment: @forpas Good point, it would have to be, e.g. `VARCHAR(255)`.

Comment: Why LONGTEXT is used for JSON value? Maybe your DBMS is MariaDB, not MySQL? *Error message* It is produced by client, not by MySQL.

Comment: If you need to assign some default value to LONGTEXT column then use BEFORE INSERT trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to use a string as a default for your longtext column, but you are missing the `DEFAULT` keyword.

But it won't work anyway.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html says:

> BLOB and TEXT columns cannot have DEFAULT values.

If I add the `DEFAULT` keyword to your example, and try it in the MySQL client, I get this error:

> ERROR 1101 (42000): BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY or JSON column 'health' can't have a default value

MariaDB, a fork of MySQL, added the capability to add a DEFAULT value to a BLOB or TEXT column in MariaDB 10.2.1, but this is not supported in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to assign some default value to LONGTEXT column then use BEFORE INSERT trigger.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT, txt LONGTEXT NOT NULL);
> CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_setdef
> BEFORE INSERT ON test
> FOR EACH ROW
> SET NEW.txt = COALESCE(NEW.txt, '["default value"]');
> INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, '["specified value"]'), (2, NULL);
> INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (3);
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | txt                
> -: | :------------------
>  1 | ["specified value"]
>  2 | ["default value"]  
>  3 | ["default value"]
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=64fcafe6a8cf1472a3d1cb8afd5cf844)*